# Page transition animation triggered when clicking on show/hide button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, toggle, transition

I am a novice to  website programming but have successfully tweaked some CSS code of the Wordpress theme I am using: Expositio (wpshower / themes / expositio).

There is a CSS Page Transition code (or so I believe):

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;  /*added cos there's no content!*/
  background-color: yellow; /*added for clarity*/
}

.site {
  opacity: .5; /*adjusted from 0*/
  position: relative;
  min-width: 320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s, left 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.main-content,
.content-area {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* Infinite load */

@-webkit-keyframes buffer1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes buffer1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes buffer1 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes buffer1 {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes buffer1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes buffer2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes buffer2 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes buffer2 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes buffer2 {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes buffer2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

#infinite-loader {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#infinite-loader.active {
  display: block;
}

#infinite-loader>* {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#infinite-loader>*:nth-child(1) {
  background: transparent;
}

#infinite-loader>*:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: buffer1 0.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: buffer1 0.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: buffer1 0.5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: buffer1 0.5s infinite;
  animation: buffer1 0.5s infinite;
}

#infinite-loader>*:nth-child(3) {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: buffer2 0.2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: buffer2 0.2s infinite;
  -o-animation: buffer2 0.2s infinite;
  -ms-animation: buffer2 0.2s infinite;
  animation: buffer2 0.2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="site"> <!-- #page -->   
    <div id="wrapper"> <!-- #wrapper -->    
      <div class="main-content">  <!-- #main -->     
        <p>hello</p>
        <span id="infinite-loader"> </span>
        <span> </span>
        <span> </span>
        <span> </span>
        <!--<?php wp_footer(); ?>--->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>SIMON VERMEULEN</title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/xmlrpc.php">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/favicon.png" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="SIMON VERMEULEN &raquo; Feed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="SIMON VERMEULEN &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/comments/feed/" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/simonvermeulen.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7.5"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var b,c,d,e,f=String.fromCharCode;if(!k||!k.fillText)return!1;switch(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.textBaseline="top",k.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return k.fillText(f(55356,56826,55356,56819),0,0),!(j.toDataURL().length<3e3)&&(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57331,65039,8205,55356,57096),0,0),b=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57331,55356,57096),0,0),c=j.toDataURL(),b!==c);case"emoji4":return k.fillText(f(55357,56425,55356,57341,8205,55357,56507),0,0),d=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55357,56425,55356,57341,55357,56507),0,0),e=j.toDataURL(),d!==e}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i,j=b.createElement("canvas"),k=j.getContext&&j.getContext("2d");for(i=Array("flag","emoji4"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='page-list-style-css'  href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/page-list/css/page-list.css?ver=5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bg-shce-genericons-css'  href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/show-hidecollapse-expand/assets/css/genericons/genericons.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bg-show-hide-css'  href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/show-hidecollapse-expand/assets/css/bg-show-hide.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='expositio-font-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lusitana%3A400%2C700' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='expositio-style-css'  href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/style.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='expositio-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
html {
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 32px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 32px);
    height: calc(100% - 32px);
}

@media (min-width: 951px) {
    .site-header {
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 32px);
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 32px);
        height: calc(100% - 32px);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 782px) {
    html {
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 46px);
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 46px);
        height: calc(100% - 46px);
    }
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.7.5" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimonvermeulen.com%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimonvermeulen.com%2F&#038;format=xml" />
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
<link rel="icon" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-180x180.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-270x270.png" />
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-38407287-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>

<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-1267 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
            <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/" rel="home">SIMON VERMEULEN</a></h1>
                <h1 class="menu-toggle">m</h1>
                <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
                    <span id="navigation-close">&#10005;</span>
                    <div id="top-main-menu" class="menu-work-container"><ul id="menu-work" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-1241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1241"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/der-untermensch/"><em>Der Untermensch</em></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1423" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-1423"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/stills/">Stills</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1221" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1221"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/glass-shoes/">Glass Shoes</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>                 <div id="top-right-menu" class="menu-more-container"><ul id="menu-more" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-1381" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1381"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1382" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1382"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/contact-press/">Contact / Press</a></li>
</ul></div>             </nav>
                <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
                        <div class="site-info">

                    </div><!-- .site-info -->
                    <div class="copyright">&#169; 2017 Simon Vermeulen. All Rights Reserved.</div>
                </footer><!-- #colophon -->
            </header><!-- #masthead -->
            <div id="header-helper"></div>

            <div id="main" class="site-main">
    <div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<article id="post-1267" class="post-1267 page type-page status-publish hentry">

    <div class="entry-content">
        <h5>News</h5>
<h6>June 8 – July 14, 2017<br />
<em>Transformation</em><br />
Le Livart, Montreal (group show)</p>
<p>Opening: June 8, 2017</h6>
<p>With Marie-Josée Bergeron, Zoé Boivin, Robert Chayer, Guillaume Cloutier, Jacynthe Cloutier, Emily Comeau, Pablo-Martín Córdoba, Alex Côté, Marc Dupuis, Antony Gasnier, Annie-Claude Généreux, Makwanda et Julia Hall, Symon Henry, Thierry Huard, Sylvie Plante, Laurence Rivest, Michaëlle Sergile, Véronique Tremblay and Éric Villeneuve.</p>
<p>For the first time in a gallery, Simon Vermeulen presents <a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/der-untermensch/"><em>Der Untermensch</em></a>, a short dance film portraying a persecuted homosexual during the Third Reich taking refuge in his imagination to find freedom from within. The <a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/glass-shoes/">glass shoes</a> featured in the film will also be exposed.</p>
<p>For further information see: <a href="http://lelivart.com">www.lelivart.com</a></p>
<p><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/der-untermensch/"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-1480 size-large" src="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/00092948-1-1024x540.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="540" srcset="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/00092948-1-1024x540.jpg 1024w, http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/00092948-1-300x158.jpg 300w, http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/00092948-1-768x405.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" /></a></p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!--

--><!--

    --><ul class="gallery gallery-animated">
    <!--
    --></ul><!--

    --> </div><!-- #main-content -->


            </div><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #page -->
    </div><!-- #wrapper -->

    <span id="infinite-loader">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </span>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=4.7.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-slide.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-highlight.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-fold.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-blind.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/show-hidecollapse-expand/assets/js/bg-show-hide.js?ver=4.7.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/js/functions.js?ver=20140321'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.5'></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.className = document.body.className.replace( /(^|\s)(no-)?customize-support(?=\s|$)/, '' ) + ' no-customize-support';
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

                        request = true;

                b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
                // The customizer requires postMessage and CORS (if the site is cross domain)
                b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
            }());
        </script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
            <div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs">
                            <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="#wp-toolbar" tabindex="1">Skip to toolbar</a>
                        <div class="quicklinks" id="wp-toolbar" role="navigation" aria-label="Toolbar" tabindex="0">
                <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/about.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="screen-reader-text">About WordPress</span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-about"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a>      </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item" href="https://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentation</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a>     </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/">SIMON VERMEULEN</a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a>     </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a>        </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-customize" class="hide-if-no-customize"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimonvermeulen.com%2F">Customize</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-updates"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/update-core.php" title="2 Plugin Updates"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">2</span><span class="screen-reader-text">2 Plugin Updates</span></a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0" aria-hidden="true">0</span><span class="screen-reader-text">0 comments awaiting moderation</span></a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post-new.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a>       </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1267&#038;action=edit">Edit Page</a>       </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class="admin-bar-search"><div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1"><form action="http://simonvermeulen.com/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /><label for="adminbar-search" class="screen-reader-text">Search</label><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search"/></form></div>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/profile.php">Howdy, admin<img alt='' src='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=26&#038;d=blank&#038;r=g' srcset='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=52&amp;d=blank&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-26 photo' height='26' width='26' /></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/profile.php"><img alt='' src='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=64&#038;d=blank&#038;r=g' srcset='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=128&amp;d=blank&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>admin</span></a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=2fed4da8ed">Log Out</a>        </li></ul></div>        </li></ul>          </div>
                        <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=2fed4da8ed">Log Out</a>
                    </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Now, I would like to use a toggle text link on my pages to show/hide text (I found a plugin: http://showhide.bunte-giraffe.de).

**When I click on the toggle link, the page transition animation is triggered, making the page content disappear, but staying on the same page.**

Can anyone of you help me with this please, I'm not even sure if the problem is the CSS...

Please let me know if you need any further information!

Thank you ever so much!

Comment: css without accompanying html is not very helpful..

Comment: in a word.. no. Open up your page, right click and click on 'view source'. Copy the html from the source and paste it into your question (i.e Edit your question!) By the way, any tags after the closing </html> will not be taken into account.

Comment: i edited your question to include some sample html but your posting php is not useful, we need the html output (and content!)

Comment: Does this HTML work better? Thank you sooooo much for your patience!

Comment: i just looked at your css in it's entirety now. You 're using primarily absolute positioning (avoid!!! - use relative, and margin/padding  properties to position elements) Also your 100% height in the main/content area will be inherited from the wrapper anyway

Comment: Thanks Rachel, it's a pre-made theme that I installed. Any suggestions to get the same website (responsive) with less bad-coding would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were loading jquery twice - only load it once. I edited your css to remove the css in the header and put it together, i added a couple of classes to size the image, but you can do this with media queries also. You can put this css in an external style sheet OR seeing as it's wordpress, just edit the theme.

I don't see what you mean about the toggle/transition.. can you elaborate..

```css
* html,
body {
  margin-top: 32px !important;
}

html {
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 32px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 32px);
  height: calc(100% - 32px);
}

img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
  display: inline !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  height: 1em !important;
  width: 1em !important;
  margin: 0 .07em !important;
  vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
  background: none !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

img.size-large {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: auto;
}

img.size-medium {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  max-width: 768px;
  height: auto;
}

img.size-small {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  max-width: 480px;
  height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 951px) {
  .site-header {
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 32px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 32px);
    height: calc(100% - 32px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 782px) {
  html {
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 46px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 46px);
    height: calc(100% - 46px);
  }
}

@media print {
  #wpadminbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>SIMON VERMEULEN</title>
  <!---  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <link rel="pingback" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/xmlrpc.php">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/favicon.png" />--->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
  <!---  <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="SIMON VERMEULEN &raquo; Feed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/feed/" />
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="SIMON VERMEULEN &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/comments/feed/" />--->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window._wpemojiSettings = {
      "baseUrl": "https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/72x72\/",
      "ext": ".png",
      "svgUrl": "https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/svg\/",
      "svgExt": ".svg",
      "source": {
        "concatemoji": "http:\/\/simonvermeulen.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7.5"
      }
    };
    ! function(a, b, c) {
      function d(a) {
        var b, c, d, e, f = String.fromCharCode;
        if (!k || !k.fillText) return !1;
        switch (k.clearRect(0, 0, j.width, j.height), k.textBaseline = "top", k.font = "600 32px Arial", a) {
          case "flag":
            return k.fillText(f(55356, 56826, 55356, 56819), 0, 0), !(j.toDataURL().length < 3e3) && (k.clearRect(0, 0, j.width, j.height), k.fillText(f(55356, 57331, 65039, 8205, 55356, 57096), 0, 0), b = j.toDataURL(), k.clearRect(0, 0, j.width, j.height), k.fillText(f(55356, 57331, 55356, 57096), 0, 0), c = j.toDataURL(), b !== c);
          case "emoji4":
            return k.fillText(f(55357, 56425, 55356, 57341, 8205, 55357, 56507), 0, 0), d = j.toDataURL(), k.clearRect(0, 0, j.width, j.height), k.fillText(f(55357, 56425, 55356, 57341, 55357, 56507), 0, 0), e = j.toDataURL(), d !== e
        }
        return !1
      }

      function e(a) {
        var c = b.createElement("script");
        c.src = a, c.defer = c.type = "text/javascript", b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)
      }
      var f, g, h, i, j = b.createElement("canvas"),
        k = j.getContext && j.getContext("2d");
      for (i = Array("flag", "emoji4"), c.supports = {
          everything: !0,
          everythingExceptFlag: !0
        }, h = 0; h < i.length; h++) c.supports[i[h]] = d(i[h]), c.supports.everything = c.supports.everything && c.supports[i[h]], "flag" !== i[h] && (c.supports.everythingExceptFlag = c.supports.everythingExceptFlag && c.supports[i[h]]);
      c.supports.everythingExceptFlag = c.supports.everythingExceptFlag && !c.supports.flag, c.DOMReady = !1, c.readyCallback = function() {
        c.DOMReady = !0
      }, c.supports.everything || (g = function() {
        c.readyCallback()
      }, b.addEventListener ? (b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", g, !1), a.addEventListener("load", g, !1)) : (a.attachEvent("onload", g), b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function() {
        "complete" === b.readyState && c.readyCallback()
      })), f = c.source || {}, f.concatemoji ? e(f.concatemoji) : f.wpemoji && f.twemoji && (e(f.twemoji), e(f.wpemoji)))
    }(window, document, window._wpemojiSettings);
  </script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='page-list-style-css' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/page-list/css/page-list.css?ver=5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='bg-shce-genericons-css' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/show-hidecollapse-expand/assets/css/genericons/genericons.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='bg-show-hide-css' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/show-hidecollapse-expand/assets/css/bg-show-hide.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='expositio-font-css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lusitana%3A400%2C700' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='expositio-style-css' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/style.css?ver=4.7.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <!--  <style id='expositio-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
    style with an id???
  </style>--->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
  <link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-json/' />
  <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
  <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
  <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.7.5" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/" />
  <link rel='shortlink' href='http://simonvermeulen.com/' />
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimonvermeulen.com%2F" />
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimonvermeulen.com%2F&#038;format=xml" />
  <link rel="icon" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-180x180.png" />
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cropped-White-Site-Icon-270x270.png" />
  <!---  <script> analytics not required onSO!
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async = 1;
      a.src = g;
      m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-38407287-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>--->
</head>

<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-1267 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
      <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/" rel="home">SIMON VERMEULEN</a></h1>
        <h1 class="menu-toggle">m</h1>
        <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
          <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
          <span id="navigation-close">&#10005;</span>
          <div id="top-main-menu" class="menu-work-container">
            <ul id="menu-work" class="nav-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-1241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1241"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/der-untermensch/"><em>Der Untermensch</em></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-1423" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-1423"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/stills/">Stills</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1221" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1221"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/glass-shoes/">Glass Shoes</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="top-right-menu" class="menu-more-container">
            <ul id="menu-more" class="nav-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-1381" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1381"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/about/">About</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-1382" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1382"><a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/contact-press/">Contact / Press</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
          <div class="site-info">

          </div>
          <!-- .site-info -->
          <div class="copyright">&#169; 2017 Simon Vermeulen. All Rights Reserved.</div>
        </footer>
        <!-- #colophon -->
      </header>
      <!-- #masthead -->
      <div id="header-helper"></div>

      <div id="main" class="site-main">
        <div id="main-content" class="main-content">

          <article id="post-1267" class="post-1267 page type-page status-publish hentry">

            <div class="entry-content">
              <h5>News</h5>
              <h6>June 8 – July 14, 2017<br> <em>Transformation</em><br><span>Le Livart, Montreal (group show)</span>>Opening: June 8, 2017</h6>
              <p>With Marie-Josée Bergeron, Zoé Boivin, Robert Chayer, Guillaume Cloutier, Jacynthe Cloutier, Emily Comeau, Pablo-Martín Córdoba, Alex Côté, Marc Dupuis, Antony Gasnier, Annie-Claude Généreux, Makwanda et Julia Hall, Symon Henry, Thierry
                Huard, Sylvie Plante, Laurence Rivest, Michaëlle Sergile, Véronique Tremblay and Éric Villeneuve.</p>
              <p>For the first time in a gallery, Simon Vermeulen presents <a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/der-untermensch/"><em>Der Untermensch</em></a>, a short dance film portraying a persecuted homosexual during the Third Reich taking refuge in his
                imagination to find freedom from within. The <a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/glass-shoes/">glass shoes</a> featured in the film will also be exposed.</p>
              <p>For further information see: <a href="http://lelivart.com">www.lelivart.com</a></p>
              <p>
                <a href="http://simonvermeulen.com/der-untermensch/"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-1480 size-large" src="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/00092948-1-1024x540.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="540" src="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/00092948-1-1024x540.jpg"></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>
          <ul class="gallery gallery-animated">
            <!--
    -->
          </ul>
          <!--

    -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- #main -->
    </div>
    <!-- #page -->
  </div>
  <!-- #wrapper -->

  <span id="infinite-loader">
        <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  </span>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=4.7.5'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-slide.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-highlight.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-fold.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect-blind.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/plugins/show-hidecollapse-expand/assets/js/bg-show-hide.js?ver=4.7.5'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-content/themes/expositio/js/functions.js?ver=20140321'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.5'></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.className = document.body.className.replace( /(^|\s)(no-)?customize-support(?=\s|$)/, '' ) + ' no-customize-support';
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var request, b = document.body,
        c = 'className',
        cs = 'customize-support',
        rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?' + cs + '(\\s+|$)');

      request = true;

      b[c] = b[c].replace(rcs, ' ');
      // The customizer requires postMessage and CORS (if the site is cross domain)
      b[c] += (window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-') + cs;
    }());
  </script>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <!---wordpress crap <div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs">
    <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="#wp-toolbar" tabindex="1">Skip to toolbar</a>
    <div class="quicklinks" id="wp-toolbar" role="navigation" aria-label="Toolbar" tabindex="0">
      <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/about.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="screen-reader-text">About WordPress</span></a>
          <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-about"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a> </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item" href="https://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentation</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/">SIMON VERMEULEN</a>
          <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a> </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-customize" class="hide-if-no-customize"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimonvermeulen.com%2F">Customize</a> </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-updates"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/update-core.php" title="2 Plugin Updates"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">2</span><span class="screen-reader-text">2 Plugin Updates</span></a> </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0" aria-hidden="true">0</span><span class="screen-reader-text">0 comments awaiting moderation</span></a>          </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post-new.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a>
          <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1267&#038;action=edit">Edit Page</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class="admin-bar-search">
          <div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1">
            <form action="http://simonvermeulen.com/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /><label for="adminbar-search" class="screen-reader-text">Search</label><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search" /></form>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/profile.php">Howdy, admin<img alt='' src='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=26&#038;d=blank&#038;r=g' srcset='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=52&amp;d=blank&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-26 photo' height='26' width='26' /></a>
          <div
            class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info">
                <a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/profile.php"><img alt='' src='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=64&#038;d=blank&#038;r=g' srcset='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/2f1fc2ebbbe6ae67e11671b5765ee1c9?s=128&amp;d=blank&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-64 photo'
                    height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>admin</span></a>
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a> </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=2fed4da8ed">Log Out</a> </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="http://simonvermeulen.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=2fed4da8ed">Log Out</a>
  </div>--->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there's no toggle link that i can see? update the css  in wordpress and remove it from the php

Comment: Thanks Rachel! Whenever I run this plugin http://showhide.bunte-giraffe.de, it activates the page transition. This is an example: http://simonvermeulen.com/francais/ click on 'Show more' and you'll see :)

Comment: hey, great can you accept my answer then? hover beside answer and a checkmark appears - click it. It'll turn green, cheers!

Comment: now see that's not working cos you have jquery twice in the header... you should also put the jquery ui in the header. Why not just use jquery ui instead of the component bits?

Comment: I will Rachel, but I have no idea what to remove and what to paste and where in my editor in Wordpress! Is it hearder.php that I need to change? And what part of the CSS is it affecting?

Comment: i don't know what's in your wp theme so i don't know for sure and i can't read the php files, as they are on the server, so I only know what the output is. The head bit of the document is most likely in header.php.. I'd start there.. important to remove the dupicate jquery file

Comment: you should change the top/left/etc to margin-top, margin-left etc while you're at it

Comment: then you could use relative positioning, much better when it comes to responsive design!.. happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not really getting this, but I guess it's advanced stuff 
Do you have any recommendations of another way to get the same look for the website but with better coding?

Comment: Well, I have about 790 answers, you could sift through those...  I'm not clear exactly what you're looking for .. is it toggle or what? If you click on the toggle tag below your question, other questions related to toggle will come up.. I edited your tags!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem.. don't hesitate to ask more questions if you don't find exactly what you're looking for!!